# unsupported operand types in python

Tags: python, selenium

Following is the code I use for taking screenshots using Python (selenium)

```
path = os.mkdir('D:\screenshots' + time.strftime("%d%m"))
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(path + '\wishlist_' + str(i) + '.jpg')
```

However when i run this program, I am getting the following error,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\domain.py", line 43, in test_bkpdomains

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(path + '\wishlist_' + str(i) + '.jpg')
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Anyone pls help me to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to concatenate an empty object with a string in the second line.

For example,

```
import os
path = os.mkdir('dummy')
print path
```

Returns `None` so you can't combine that with the strings in the second line. Perhaps if you make the directory and then just use the string for its path in the second line:

```
path = '/path/to/directory' #string for usage below (can be concatenated)
os.mkdir(path) #make the actual directory 
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(path + '/wishlist_' + str(i) + '.jpg')
```